# How to get Lambda functions configuration using async await?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I want to get the configuration of a lambda function using the [GetFunctionConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/lambda-2015-03-31/GetFunctionConfiguration) API.

Currently the code I am using is based on callbacks but I want to transform it to use `async await`.

```
var params = {
  FunctionName: "my-function",
};

lambda.getFunctionConfiguration(params, function (err, data) {
  // Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. Chaining a `.promise` call will return a promise so it can now be used with async/await.

```
const data = await lambda.getFunctionConfiguration(params).promise()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can promisify your function with

```
const util = require('util');
const getFunctionConfiguration = util.promisify(lambda.getFunctionConfiguration);
```

and call it with

```
const data = await getFunctionConfiguration(params);
```

You can find more on promisify here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: Ya that works well (UPVOTED), but I wanted to know does AWS provide some async version of these functions already?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee `lambda.getFunctionConfiguration` is an asynchronous function using callbacks. You can transform it to an asynchronous function using promises.